# Wordpress how to drop a column in table using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to drop a column in a table with the Wordpress database using `$wpdb` but this is not working:

```php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}wc_product_meta_lookup DROP column_to_drop");
```

Wordpress does not seem to give me an error. I run it but absolutely nothing happens to the column. I'm very new to PHP and I'm almost giving up...

Keep in mind that I am able to add columns to tables without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day, Gustav
Try to use this function

```
function maybe_drop_column( $table_name, $column_name, $drop_ddl ) {}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_drop_column/

$table_name
(string) (Required) Database table name.

$column_name
(string) (Required) Table column name.

$drop_ddl
(string) (Required) SQL statement to drop column.

[image]

Tell please if it works...